Solving a pair of PDEs by Kampé de Fériet function and other functions
I have a pair of PDEs as follow:
$$\left(1+2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+6y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(2+2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+6y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)w=\left(2+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+5y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)w_x$$
$$\prod_{t=1}^{6}\left(t+2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+6y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)w=\prod_{t=2}^{6}\left(t+x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+5y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)w_y$$
Where $w=w(x,y)$
Question: Is it possible to solve for $w(x,y)$ in terms of Kampé de Fériet function and other functions such as trigonometric functions, generalized hypergeometric function,...?

These PDEs look pretty nasty. Variable coefficients, singularities at $x=0$ and $y=0$, and a strong nonlinearity in the second equation. We usually do not expect explicit solutions to be available unless a DE is MUCH simpler than this.

The only hope is that there may be some special structure to exploit, such as a transformation or other trick that shows the system is simpler than it looks. Any such structure would likely be related to where the equations came from. So, how did you come to write these PDEs down?

@user1149748 I simply took out an infinite series representations of a root of a sextic from here and write out the differential equation that has solution as that series, and I was hoping to get an answer which leads to solving general sextic equation by Kampé de Fériet function

How did you find the differential equation? Maybe it is like differential resolvents. Perhaps it can be written out a bit.

@ТymaGaidash yes, I compare with a pair of PDEs with solution as the Kampé de Fériet function and come up with that

@ТymaGaidash i found an error while constructing the RHS of the second PDE, and I also edit the RHS of the first one so that it looks right(althought it's the same but with an extra x), hope you can review
